# Qt - How does Qt catch the unconncted click event(auto-connect)?

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using Qt plugin with VS2010.
Defined a button named `ButtonA` and a slot named `on_ButtonA_clicked()` in the main window class. But I have not stated `connect(ButtonA, SIGNAL(clicked), this, SLOT(on_ButtonA_clicked()` and I found that `on_ButtonA_clicked()` slot is still able to catch the click event of `ButtonA`.
Also found that slot `on_ButtonName_clicked()` can catch any button as long as `ButtonName` is the name of the button. Can anyone tell me why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Qt automatically generates connections for controls defined in UI files. If you are calling `setupUi`, that's what is happening. For more information about this functionality, see [the documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/designer-using-a-ui-file.html#widgets-and-dialogs-with-auto-connect).